# Angular and Meteor flicker on page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-meteor

I had an issue with and angular-meteor project flickering every time a state using the campaigns subscription, would load.  By flickering, I mean the data was there, then it would go away and come back a half second later.

I added this to the `resolve` property of the state (using ui-router):

```
campaigns: ($q) => {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  Meteor.subscribe('campaigns', {
    onReady: deferred.resolve,
    onStop: deferred.reject
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

The flickering stopped, but I don't really understand this code.  Can someone who understand angular break this resolve/defer situation down?

Just not sure why it worked.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$q is angular's implementation of promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

in a very itty bitty nutshell, a promise has two callbacks that resolve when data is returned; a resolve function if the call succeeds and a reject if the call fails. whatever data it gets will be passed into these functions (essentially doing deferred.resolve(data) or deferred.reject(error)) . $q.defer() allows us to assign the resolution/rejections later.

[meteor's subscribe function takes a few arguments](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.6/subscribe#arguments). the string name of the collection, a function that returns an array of arguments to be passed to the collection, and an object/function. the object part of the final argument expects an "onReady" and "onStop" functions, and will execute those functions and pass along any data it gets. we pass in our callbacks here.

finally, we return the promise. resolve.campaigns will be a promise, which we can get the values from using the .then(successCallback, failureCallback) call. meteor handles this behind the scenes.